# Dotenv Webpack - When I change the system environment variables on runtime, the changes is not affected on the app

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables, dotenv

I build a web app using react, webpack, docker and AWS.

I create a feature which depends on environment variable. So if the environment variable value is true, the feature will be showing on the frontend.

The problem is, when I changed the environment variable on the server (Webpack already done building the app, the app is already deployed and running), my feature is not showing. I guess due to the app cannot read the value changes on system environment variable.

How can I achieve this ? is it possible to do it ?

=====

I use **dotenv webpack** for managing my environment variables. I already set the **systemvars** to **true** to detect all environment variables from the system or .env file.

=====

So why am I doing this, because I dont want to make a Pull Request to push a new value for environment variables. I just want to reserve the environment variables name, and change the value directly from the server if the feature is ready to deployed. And if there is an error, I just need to change the environment variable to something and the feature is down.

Comment: Post-build, the JavaScript bundle is fixed. If you want a change of env var on the server to alter the behaviour, you need the server to expose that via e.g. an API endpoint so the client can consume the configuration and respond appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for give me such a great insight.

Actually, I was thinking that javascript bundle is fixed but I am not sure. Could you help me to find any references for this fixed bundle? Thank you so much. @jonrsharpe

Comment: What do you mean *"references for this fixed bundle"*? Just look at what you're serving.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is like an article that explain javascript bundle is fixed (fixed example is cant change the env on runtime). I just want to share it with my colleagues.

Comment: Can't *they* look at what you're serving? By all means look for one but I don't know what would count as an appropriate reference that the output if Webpacking your code is a JS file to serve.

Comment: Alright, will try it today. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cant change environment variable. Evn variables loaded on compile/webpack load time. So once app start u cant change, `process.env`.

Solution as @jonrsharpe explains. You need to create, some sort of database. It could be memory or file or database. You read data from that. Expose a API, to update the data base.

Express sample:

```
global.enableFeature = false

app.post("/updateFeatureToggle", (req, res) => {
  const enableFeature = req.body.enableFeature

  global.enableFeature = enableFeature
  res.send({success: "OK"})
})
```

In another file, read from `global.enableFeature`. This is in memory-based.

Comment: Thanks for the memory based example for solving this. I think, I need talk about this with my team again.

Comment: @SaddamHabibie thanks.. please accept as answer ! :-D